# how to get foreign key set in relationship of Laravel 9

Tags: eloquent, foreign-keys, relationship, laravel-9

I'm using Larave 9 to build a complicated web application.
I'm trying to get foreign key already set in relationship of a model to make another dynamic join query for some other data.

This is an example to make a dynamic query after getting foreign keys from many models:

```
foreach ($joinFunc as $table => $jQ){
  $relTbl = $jQ['related'];
  $k = $jQ['oKey'];
  $fk = $jQ['fKey'];
  $q->leftJoin($table, $table. '.' . $k, $relTbl. '.' .$fk);
}
```

My relationship in model is:

```
public function autopays()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ClientAutoPay::class, 'client_id', 'id');
    }
```

I want to get `client_id` set in the relationship

```
$q = Client::query()->with('autopays');
dump(
  $q->first()->autopays()->getRelated()->getKeyName(),
  $q->first()->autopays()->getRelated()->getForeignKey(),
);
```

but the result id:

`"id"`
`"client_auto_pay_id"`

what I need is to get `client_id` instead of `client_auto_pay_id`. Any help :(

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to check if the relationship has an instance (`$q->whereHas()`) which gave me the table name and if no instance found then I didn't pass it to dynamic joining query loop.

One thing I had to pass manually from the controller to my function and that is array of each table joining ownKeys and foreignKeys.

Now my dynamic dataTable by Livewire component is working awesome